# Is there a method to make Multipart or Virtual Files?

Tags: ssh, files, symlink, lvm

Is there a method of creating a symbolic file that refers to the contents of a directory?

So for example, calling:

`cat all_keys`

would give the same output as:

`cat keys/key1+keys/key2+etc...`

I've tried creating a symbolic link to the directory, tried various flags to try and get the Data and even trying to make a symbolic link that runs the command:

`cat keys/*`

Akin to the manner in which Logical Volume can span multiple physical partitions, I'd like to know if I can create a file that spans an arbitrary and flexible length of data.

For context: I'm getting really frustrated with the flatfile system used for ssh authorised_keys.

I know I could use a SED to remove the key data but that seems messy. I'm sure there's other uses outside of this scope too.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

In the end I just went with SED in place to make the deletions and comments before the key block to identify it.

It's a little more expensive CPU wise than I'd have liked, but avoids either repeating all the key data in a folder and a file or trying to make a fuse directory.

Comment: while I never use it myslef, this sound like fuse filesystem.

Comment: Possibly, or a new type of symbolic link. I fear that writing a new FS or link type may well be beyond my ability - but if all else fails, I'll give it a try.

Comment: This is a user level FS.

Comment: Cheers, Archemar, I'm looking into it just in case, I'll be honest though, this is deeper into C++ than I'm currently familiar or comfortable with, so if push comes to shove, I'll fall back on a SED script for this use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this that I know of would be to write a new filesystem, probably at the user-level using FUSE or similar. This isn't intractable (I've done it in ~200 lines of Python), but it's a fair bit of fiddly detail work, and it may not be the best fit for this application (in particular, you would need to mount the new FS on `.ssh`, meaning you also have to emulate a real filesystem or pass requests through to handle the other flat files which need to be in there).

Another option might be to write a script which generates the flat file from a source directory (which might be as simple as `cat dir/* >file`), then run it on a cronjob or triggered by inotify or similar. A simple script might be:

```
while inotifywait ~/ssh_source_dir; do
    cat ~/ssh_source_dir/* >~/.ssh/authorized_keys
done
```

(Which assuredly needs tuning for precise behavior and reliability, but it's a prototype.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in the end though I just went with a combo of SED editing in place and using comments to identify the keys, messy but it avoids having duplicate data.

Comment: (sorry for the belated acceptance, this was the only viable and efficient solution in the end)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to chop a large file like your `allkeys` file into pieces.

read `man split` for the options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I fear that it wouldn't fare well with key data, some users use 1024bits, others use 2048bits.

Ideally, what I'm hoping to do is the inverse of that, a file that when read, joins multiple files into one on the fly, avoiding the need for pattern matching, digging and triage.

Split will definitely help with other things I write though, thanks!